# Show two values in one select from two different camps

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to put two values in one select input.
I have my table with `n_processo`(ID) and `nome` (name), and I want the select to show n_processo + nome like "10293 - John".
My select is on the function `DBRead14` on the code down.

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope icon"></i>
    <?php $dts1 = DBRead14(); ?>
    <select name="n_processo" id="n_processo" required class="input-field">
    <?php
        foreach($dts1 as $option) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option['n_processo']; ?>"><?php echo $option['n_processo' - 'nome']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

```
function DBRead14() 
{
  $sql = "SELECT n_processo,nome FROM aluno";
  $result = DBExecute($sql);

  $dts = array();

  while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dts1[] = $res;
  }

  return $dts1;
}
```

Comment: Change `<?php echo $option['n_processo' - 'nome']; ?>` to `<?php echo $option['n_processo' ]; ?> - <?php echo $option['nome' ]; ?>`.

Comment: @marv255 I'm guessing that your comment is the solution to this question.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! How can I close this case?

Comment: @marv255 please add this as an answer so it may be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$dts1` is an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). We need to use a key to get some data (value) from it: `$option['n_processo']`.

In you case you want to get to values and [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) them in a one [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

So there are three operations: getting a value with a key `n_processo`, getting a value with a key `nome` and concatenation of these two values.

```
<?php echo $option['n_processo'] . ' - ' . $option['nome']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should concatenate your values

```
<option value="<?php echo $option['n_processo'] . ' - ' . $option['nome']; ?>SOME_TIELE</option>
```